# How to write Cypress code that can handle different fields in different environments?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

In my Project, I have two Environments.

- in the first Environment, the field is *Manufacturing Date* *
- and in the second Environment *Manufacturing Year* *

I run the code in both Environments, But the problem is that the field has changed respectively. So I have to type the date in one Env and select the year in the second env.

I have tried this one
cy.get(this.Element).then((el)=>{

```
        if(el.text()==='Manufacturing Date *'){
            cy.wrap(el).type('13/04/2023')
        }

        else if(el.text()==='Manufacturing Year *'){
            cy.wrap(el).click()
            cy.contains('2023').click()
        }
    })
```

But I did not automate the text
I am Expecting that when I run the code in 1st Env it select Manufacturing Date * and run the code on 2nd Env
it selects Manufacturing Year *.

Comment: Can you update the source code of the app ? Because it would be easier to have a special attribute `cy-data="..."` so you would avoid to check by the text

Comment: Yes it will be udating soon but right now i have to automate that

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript `.includes()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to do this

```js
if (el.text().includes('Manufacturing Date')) {
  cy.wrap(el).type('13/04/2023')
}

if (el.text().includes('Manufacturing Year')) {
  cy.wrap(el).click()
  cy.contains('2023').click()
}
```

or even better... `.startsWith()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
if (el.text().startsWith('Manufacturing Date')) {
  cy.wrap(el).type('13/04/2023')
}

if (el.text().startsWith('Manufacturing Year')) {
  cy.wrap(el).click()
  cy.contains('2023').click()
}
```

Comment: Did not work both solutions